# How to auto reload an iFrame without blinking in jQuery every second?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I would like to auto reload an iFrame that is in my webpage called "dispatch1.php" every second without having it constantly blinking. Here is my line of HTML code with the iFrame.

```
<iframe id="dispatch1" src="table.php" name="dispatch1" width="800px" height="400px" style="margin-right:10%;margin-top:10%;"></iframe>
```

This is the code that I have so far with the jQuery, but it isn't working.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
    $.get('table.php', function(data) {
        $('#dispatch1').html(data);    
    });
}
</script>
```

Edit: I have fixed the problem. I just remove the code from the iFrame and put it into the dispatch1.php file.

Comment: you could use smarter html\ajax than an iframe. why not populate a div ?

Comment: With a div, for some reason it messes up the whole page with the different element positioning.

Comment: im sure the right css\html will fix that  fine

Comment: I've tried to, although, for some reason the table mixes in with some other elements on the page and it looks very weird. I'll continue to try and fix it with CSS, but I'm still looking for other ways I could make this work.